# Can we load image in picture control from a buffer in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, image, camera, load, buffer

I need to load an image into picture control from a camera connected to my PC.

I captured data from the camera into a buffer but I don't know how to load image in picture control from the buffer.

The first byte of my buffer is pointed by an unsigned short pointer. For GUI I am using the default library that Visual Studio 2015 offers.

Comment: Yes, it is entirely possible, and can be done in many different ways. Unless you tell us what UI framework you're using and the format of the image buffer is, the chances are no-one will be able to answer your question.

Comment: the first byte of my buffer is pointed by an unsigned short pointer, For GUI i am using the default library that Visual Studio 2015 offers

Comment: You are still not providing enough information. What format is the image stored raw bmp or a stream like jpeg

Comment: Image in buffer is ready to be displayed and the data is in tif format